# autoincrement udf in hive

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive

I have created a udf in hive to add auto increment column in hive.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class AutoIncrUdf extends UDF {
    int Value;

    public int evaluate() {
        Value++;
        return Value;
    }
}
```

I have created a temporary function `temp` while using on my table as

```
Select temp() from table1;
```

it is giving all rows as:

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

And so on. But I want it as

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: hi @bat_rock I am stuck at the same problem. Commenting to check if you found any solution in last 4 years :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use below code for autoincrement udf in hive:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;

@UDFType(deterministic = false)
public class AutoIncrementUDF extends UDF {

    int ctr ;

    public int evaluate() {
        ctr++;
        return ctr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour to get idea on how to write better answer. This is 3 years old question and your answer isn't different then the one below from @neerajyadav? Something changed in meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. One instance of UDF class is created per call. Maybe try `static int Value;` .. GL

Comment: Yeah, this should work. But be ware this type of UDF depends on all the rows doing through one mapper/reducer to have rows perfectly numbered. Likely not your specific problem here since you end up with dups not all the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Add stateful attribute to your class:

```
@UDFType(stateful = true)
public class AutoIncrUdf extends UDF {
    ...
}
```

The addition of annotation `@UDFType(stateful = true)` is required otherwise counter value will not get increment in the Hive column, it will just return value 1 for all the rows but not the actual row number. This is the same issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

Try out the below :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udf/UDFRowSequence.java

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rowSequence AS .UDFRowSequence';

SELECT rowSequence(100) AS id, field1, field2 from 'table' where 'condition';

Comment: I had to use this command to get it to work: `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rowSequence AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence';`